# how to install vuetify 2.5.6 with vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3

here's my code in main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(vuetify)
app.mount('#app')
```

and here's my code in vuetify.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
    icons: {
        iconfont: 'mdi'
    }
})
```

[here's the error message I received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJOvd.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Vue 3 (Vue CLI version doesn't matter much) and Vuetify 2.x **is not compatible** with Vue 3 - see [the docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/)

So you need to make a choice - if you want to use Vuetify 2.x, you need to switch to Vue 2. If you want to continue to work with Vue 3, you need to use [Vuetify 3](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/roadmap/#v30-titan) which is currently in [aplha stage](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v3.0.0-alpha.8)

Comment: I didn't see that the version of vue isn't applicable for vuetify 2.x this is really helpful. uhmm one thing, what can you suggest a framework that is working for vue cli 3. thanks in advance

Comment: It is hard to give any recommendations as the choice of component library depends on many things. I have some experience with both [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/) and Vuetify and I think both are solid choices. Quasar 2 (for Vue 3) came out of beta just [few days ago](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/discussions/9734)